# javascript function not working in jquery-ajax rails validation error displays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a Jquery UI Datepicker function globally to use the calendar in all the pages.
I created a seperate javascript page like the following:

```
var showDatePickers = function() {
  $('[data-field-type="date"]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm--dd",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "/assets/blue-calendar-icon.png",
    buttonText: "Calendar"
  });
}

$(showDatePickers);
```

I just post my datepicker field in my view,

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Renewal_Date %>
  <%= f.text_field :Renewal_Date, readonly: 'readonly', data: {field_type: date}}
</div>
```

I call the above function to a seperate javascript file.

```
$(function() {
  if ($('html.asset_contracts').length == 1) {
    $(document.body).on('ajax:success', '.new_asset_contract, .edit_asset_contract',     showDatePickers);
  }
});
```

It is working fine when the page loads, edit and new action. But When the rails validation error displays the datepicker function not working. It showing the blank `text_field`.

FYI: It's an ajax page and the `new, create, update and edit` action is working as `ajax` pages. So, I added `remote: true` in my form and i have `new.js, edit.js, create.js and update.js`

It's my controller,

```
def create
     @contract = Asset::Contract.new(params[:asset_contract])

     respond_to do |format|
       if @contract.save
         format.html { redirect_to asset_contracts_path, notice: "Successfully Created" }
         format.js
         format.json { render json: @contract, status: :created, location: @contract }
       else
         format.html { render action: "new" }
         format.js
         format.json { render json: @contract.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end



   def update
     @contract = Asset::Contract.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
       if @contract.update_attributes(params[:asset_contract])
         format.html { redirect_to asset_contracts_path, notice: "Succesfully Updated" }
         format.js
         format.json { head :no_content }
       else
         format.html { render action: "edit" }
         format.js
         format.json { render json: @contract.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end             
     end
   end
```

Thanks

Comment: when validates error happen,check js if modify datetime field seletor `[data-field-type="date"]`

Answer (score 5):

You're creating the datepickers like so:

```
$(document.body).on('ajax:success', '.new_asset_contract, .edit_asset_contract',     showDatePickers);
```

However, this will only run if the AJAX call is successful, so you'll need a handler for errors as well.

It appears you're using namespaced events and I don't see that referenced in the jQuery documentation. You'll probably want to use the global ajax events (e.g., ajaxComplete, ajaxError, etc.).

You'll either need to attach a separate handler for `ajaxError` to handle the error case or just use the `ajaxComplete` event in place of `ajax:success`. Unless you need specific error handling, `ajaxComplete` is the way to go, since you will only need to write/maintain one handler. As of jQuery 1.8, Global events are triggered on the `document`. You'll need to attach your listener to the document without any other selectors:

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', showDatePickers);
```

You can read more about the jQuery AJAX events on the [Ajax Events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) page.

Comment: I tried with `ajax:complete, ajax:error, ajax:success` no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I updated to use the global events instead of namespaced events. Give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: `ajax:complete` not working mate. May be I need to try to attach a separate handler for `ajaxError`. Please guide me to do that.

Comment: Did you try `ajaxComplete`? That's different than `ajax:complete`.

Comment: I also updated the way the handler is registered. See if these updates help you.

Comment: I tried ajaxComplete... its block the other javascript function as not working. This problem is not only for datepicker function. All other javascript function is also not working. :-( Thanks

Comment: nope.... there is no errors in the console. But when the validation error i get.... the javascript function is not working...

Comment: Hi.... I got an error like Cannot call method 'cloneNode' of undefined when i am using ajaxComplete. any idea please?